# Python - GUI2EXE - AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Popen'

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface, py2exe

I use Python 2.7 and py2exe and recently I downloaded gui2exe latest version (5.3). But when I try to execute the `gui2exe.py` file, it gives me an error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Popen'
```

I researched so much but never got any solution.

Please help.

Comment: Can you give the URL to gui2exe?

Comment: Could you give the full traceback?

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/gui2exe/


The image of the traceback:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11701729/Capture.PNG

Comment: Did you save one of your own scripts over C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py? Because it sure looks like it.

Comment: Nope. I even re installed Python over and over again :/

Comment: images are dead links

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like something is masking `subprocess.py` from the standard library. The error message may show a stale path. Therefore open a Python shell right in the directory you start `GUI2exe.py` from and type:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.__file__
```

This should give you `'C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.pyc'`. If not, you found the problem. Somehow another `subprocess.py` made it into your PYTHONPATH.

Comment: It returns 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\subprocess.pyc'

Comment: Look inside _'C:\\Python27\\lib\\subprocess.py'_ and see what line 2, where the error occurs says.

Comment: Ah..I tried to run Gui2Exe again and it seemed to work fine o.O